# Swift: a button to change the text in the UItextView?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to implement a button to trigger the original text I have in the UItextView. I have looked at this post:
[Trigger button to change text in UITextView in swift3 xcode 8 ios 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324319/trigger-button-to-change-text-in-uitextview-in-swift3-xcode-8-ios-10)

and followed it I realized it only worked for UItextField. Since I need to wrap the my text, I am wondering is that possible to do the similar action with UItextView?

Currently, I have:

```
@IBOutlet var Textfield: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var ChangingText: [UIButton]!


@IBAction func ChangingTextTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        Textfield.text = "Changing text here"
    }
```

But I got the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282d15b90'
```

Thanks in advance!

Solution:
It works well following the suggestion from Dejan Atanasov:

```
 @IBOutlet var Textfield: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var ChangingText: UIButton!


    @IBAction func ChangingTextTapped(_ btn: UIbutton) {
            Textfield.text = "Changing text here"
        }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the UITextView text by pressing on a button you will need the following code:

```
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var textView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var changeTextBtn: UIButton!


@IBAction func onChangeTextButton(_ btn: UIButton){
    textView.text = "Change text to something else!"
}
```

Connect the **@IBAction** with the button in the Interface Builder and make sure you select the **Touch Up Inside** event (see screenshot). That's it!

[image]

This is the result when I click on the button:

[image]

Comment: It works very well! Thank you! I think changing _btn: UIbutton is the key!

Comment: Could I can ask you a follow up question? If I have multiple text line that I want to change using the same button, could I add more lines of textView.text = "Change1!", textView.text = "Change2!" like this? Would it be possible?

Comment: No, you can't call textVew.text twice, it will just overwrite the previous value. If you want to add text in a new line, you should use textView.text = "Change1!\nChange2!".

Answer (score 1):

No need to add array of buttons.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textViewDemo: UITextView!

@IBAction func upgradeBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

textViewDemo.text = "Set Something else"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue with your code was the following line:

```
@IBOutlet var ChangingText: [UIButton]!
```

Your have declared your button as an array of UIButtons by enclosing UIButton in Brackets...[UIButton]. Simply remove the brackets.